# Laravel - you don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

To deploy laravel app on my subdomain i followed these steps:

I have root directory **/www**.
So i created directory **app** at the same level as **www/**

1. I did copy all laravel files except public into app.
2. Then i copied public files into /www
3. I have also changed index.php

from

> ```
> require __DIR__.’/../bootstrap/autoload.php’;
> $app = require_once __DIR__.’/../bootstrap/app.php’;
> ```

to

> ```
> require __DIR__.’/../app/bootstrap/autoload.php’;
> $app = require_once __DIR__.’/../app/bootstrap/app.php’;
> ```

But still getting error

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

On localhost it works fine.

My htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You could just install it regularly "anywhere" and create a new vhost named like your subdomain

Comment: most likely, you have permissions, but the user that php is running as, doesn't. what does `system("namei -l /www 2>&1");`   say?

Comment: @hanshenrik f: /www drwxr-xr-x root root / www - No such file or directory

Comment: @uppermost then /www does not exist. when you say `/www`, are you inside a chroot? in which case, you're in a chroot, PHP's user is not in a chroot

Comment: my root is  /html/domain/subdomains/name_of_subdomain, so my www is name_of_subdomain folder

Comment: did u find answer?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski no

Comment: @uppermost then, what is the output of `system("namei -l /html/domain/subdomains/name_of_subdomain 2>&1");`  ?